# How to wait in main thread for subthreads to be complete and vice versa?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

In C++, I had an update function that would iterate through an array of cubes, applying physics, then draw:

```
Update()
   {
   for each cube in cubes:
   {
      DoPhysics(cube)
   }
   Draw()
}
```

I split that array up into a number of chunks equal to the amount of threads by finding a start and end iterator. I detached these threads to Update() the cubes between each iterator.

I want to wait in the main thread for ALL the subthreads to finish their updates before Drawing. I want to wait in the subthreads for main to finish drawing before updating again.

```
Update(it start, it end)
{
   Wait Until (Main::Draw() is done)
   {
      for (it = start; it != end; it++)
      {
         DoPhysics(*it)
      }
   }
}

Update()
   {
   Wait Until (ALL Thread::Update() is done)
   {
      Draw()
   }
}
```

I tried using a mutex, and condition variables to wait, but as you have to lock a mutex to use CVs, I couldn't figure out a way to have the multiple threads fire at once. Instead, they would lock while waiting, making each thread fire sequentially.

I felt like I was missing something, so I thought I'd ask here for help: maybe there is an obvious way I have overlooked, or an std::something that could help me. I am quite tired from Uni deadlines, so it's more than possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular C++ syntax.

Comment: Perhaps consider something like [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) and [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Comment: @Eljay apologies, its just some sloppy psuedocode, I was hoping it would help explain the basic problem

Comment: if you use c++17 `std::for_each`  could execute in parallel (separate thread) [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Sirben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22997295/sirben) mentioned, the [barrier design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29) should suit you.
Unfortunately, the barrier is implemented [since C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier), but it is easy to implement any barrier restricted to your needs.

Below sample snippet where sample vector of int data is divided into the range parts and each thread processes given part, next waits for barrier completion by all threads (except the main thread in this example).

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

//! Used to print logs without the data fragmentation caused by operator << call races.
#define MY_LOG(_ostream, ...)                    \
    {                                            \
        std::stringstream _log_stream;           \
        _log_stream << __VA_ARGS__ << std::endl; \
        _ostream << _log_stream.str();           \
    }

//! Single element type.
using entry_t = int;

//! Type of elements sequence.
using entries_t = std::vector<entry_t>;

//! Dummy implementation of function applied to each element.
//! This implementation increases the element by one.
//! So when whole vector of ints will be increased from 0, 0, 0... to 1, 1, 1... it will be confirmation
//! that all elements will be processed exactly one time.
void doPhysics(entry_t& what)
{
    ++what;
}

//! Sample barrier which is completed when decrease() function is called the same times that initial size value.
struct Barrier
{
    int m_size = 0;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;

    inline Barrier(const int size)
        : m_size(size)
    {
    }

    inline void decrease()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (--m_size == 0)
        {
            m_cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    inline void try_decrease() noexcept
    {
        try
        {
            decrease();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            MY_LOG(std::cerr, "barrier: decrease() has failed()...");
        }
    }

    //! Waits for barrier completion.
    //! @return true when barrier is complete.
    //! @return false when barrier is not complete - so waiting timeout has occurred.
    template<typename DurationT>
    inline bool wait_for(const DurationT dur)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_cv.wait_for(lock, dur, [this]() {
            return m_size == 0;
        });
    }
};

//! Protects against forgetting barrier decreasing.
struct BarrierDecreaseGuard
{
    Barrier* m_barrier = nullptr;
    BarrierDecreaseGuard(Barrier* barrier)
        : m_barrier(barrier)
    {
    }

    ~BarrierDecreaseGuard() noexcept
    {
        m_barrier->try_decrease();
    }
};

void update_thread_func(const std::size_t threadIdx, const entries_t::iterator begin, const entries_t::iterator end, Barrier* barrier)
{
    try
    {
        // The barrier scope here...
        {
            BarrierDecreaseGuard decreaseOnScopeExit(barrier);
            for (entries_t::iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it)
            {
                doPhysics(*it);
            }
            // ...Barier decreases here at the end of scope.
        }

        // The thread decreased its own part of barrier and may wait for other threads here.
        if (barrier->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)))
        {
            MY_LOG(std::cout, "thread [" << threadIdx << "]: Barrier passed!");
        }
        else
        {
            MY_LOG(std::cerr, "thread [" << threadIdx << "]: Failed to wait for the barrier in update function.");
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        MY_LOG(std::cerr, "thread [" << threadIdx << "]: Thread has failed.");
    }
}

void parallelOperation(entries_t& entries, const std::size_t threadsCount)
{
    const std::size_t operationsPerThread = entries.size() / threadsCount;
    std::size_t operationsPerThreadModulo = entries.size() % threadsCount;

    Barrier barrier(threadsCount);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    entries_t::iterator it = entries.begin();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadsCount; ++i)
    {
        auto end = it + operationsPerThread;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            end += operationsPerThreadModulo;
        }
        threads.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(update_thread_func, i, it, end, &barrier)));
        it = end;
    }

    const bool waitSuccess = barrier.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    if (waitSuccess)
    {
        MY_LOG(std::cout, "thread [main]: Barier wait success.");
    }
    else
    {
        MY_LOG(std::cerr, "thread [main]: Failed to wait for barrier: timeout as occurred.");
    }

    for (std::thread& threadEntry : threads)
    {
        if (threadEntry.joinable())
        {
            threadEntry.join();
        }
    }
}

void parallelTest()
{
    entries_t sampleData(1000000, 0);
    MY_LOG(std::cout, "Sample data size: " << sampleData.size());
    parallelOperation(sampleData, 20);

    MY_LOG(std::cout, "Data verification of size: " << sampleData.size());
    for (const auto& entry : sampleData)
    {
        if (entry != 1)
        {
            MY_LOG(std::cerr, "Expecting value: 1, got: " << entry);
            assert(1 == entry);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no provided implementation of detecting exceptions thrown in threads, so this barrier could provide any possibility to set any exception pointer if needed, but it is not the main topic of this question. Should be all exceptions stored in barrier, first exception, or just `bool` information that any failure occurred. E.g. `std::future` contains `exception_ptr`, but it is related to single invocation, not a thread-set.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't figure out how to accept a comment as an answer, and can't upvote yet, but yes, I managed to implement std::barrier in the program and it worked well! Thank you both for all your help.

Comment: Thanks. Multi-threading is most dangerous and ...brutal part of programming.
You can also use bitmasks instead of decreasing counter - to detect potential bug when thread didn't release the barrier or trying to release twice (each thread has different bitmask 1, 2, 4.. and barrier initialized with all thread's bit set (7)).
If you have boost library integrated (I always use boost in my C++ commercial projects), you can consider the `boost::barrier`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/thread/barrier.hpp

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutex and probably condition variable to achieve that

it should
have a shared state defined by the shared variables `is_updated` and `is_drawn`
and use the mutex class to protect this

- in the main thread, you'll also need a waiting mechanism so that after
  launching subthreads, it'll wait until they're finished using a
  condition variable
- In the subthread signal the main thread that they are done and wait for the main thread to finish before updating again

something this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex updateMutex;
std::condition_variable updateCV;
bool isUpdated = false;

std::mutex drawMutex;
std::condition_variable drawCV;
bool isDrawn = false;

void DoPhysics(int& cube) {
    // Simulate physics
    // ...
}

void WorkerUpdate() {
    // Update logic

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(updateMutex);
        isUpdated = true;
    }
    updateCV.notify_one();
}

void MainUpdate() {
    // Launch worker threads

    // Wait for worker threads to finish updates
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(updateMutex);
        updateCV.wait(lock, [] { return isUpdated; });
    }

    // Draw logic

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(drawMutex);
        isUpdated = false;
    }
    drawCV.notify_all();
}

int main() {
    // Launch MainUpdate in a separate thread
    std::thread updateThread(MainUpdate);

    // Launch worker threads
    std::thread workerThread(WorkerUpdate);

    // Join threads
    updateThread.join();
    workerThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer, I tried a similar solution but unfortuantely with only the one update lock each update triggered one after the other, I was hoping to trigger them all simultaneously, apologies if this wan't clear enough in the question.

Comment: Have you tried a barrier sync? @IsaacDexter

Comment: I have not! I will investigate, thank you!